# Node.js how to fs.close from angular $http call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I have been struggling for many days to start and stop file reading. I have two buttons in my angular html page.One is for start and one for stop file reading process. File reading code is working on start button but the stop button is not working. Not getting any idea how to do this. Please suggest me something.

```
<button id="starttodb" style="margin-left:25px;margin-right:25px;" ng-click="starttodb()">starttodb</button>
<button id="stoptodb" style="margin-left:25px;margin-right:25px;" ng-click="stoptodb()">stoptodb</button>
```

And have two functions associated with these two buttons in controller.

```
$scope.starttodb = function() {
            var filename = 'D:\\test.txt'
                $http({
                    url: '/starttodb',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {filename: filename}                  
                    }).success(function (response) {
                                console.log("success in starttodb");                                
                    }); 
}; 
$scope.stoptodb = function() {
var filename = 'STOP'
    $http({
        url: '/starttodb',
        method: "POST",
        data: {filename: filename}
        }).success(function (response) {
                    console.log("success in starttodb");                                    
        });
};
```

Calling this file reading code in route function.

```
var bite_size = 1024,readbytes = 0,file;
var filename = req.body.filename ;
var initcontent = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    console.log('Initial File content : \n' + initcontent);
    console.log('Initial File content length: \n' + initcontent.length);
    readbytes = initcontent.length; 
            fs.watchFile(filename, function() {         
                fs.open(filename, "r", function(error, fd) {               
                    fs.read(fd, new Buffer(bite_size), 0, bite_size, readbytes, function(err, bytecount, buff) {                                  
                      console.log(buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount));
                      console.log('File Changed ...'+fd);
                      readbytes+=bytecount;
                    });             
                });
            })
```

I want to stop this file reading on stop button click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the file reading, you need to unwatch the file (by a specific listened if you will have multiple clients)

Your start function will look like this:

```
// outside of the route
var watchers = []  

// inside the route
var bite_size = 1024,readbytes = 0,file;
var filename = req.body.filename ;
var initcontent = fs.readFileSync(filename);
console.log('Initial File content : \n' + initcontent);
console.log('Initial File content length: \n' + initcontent.length);
readbytes = initcontent.length;

var watcherFunction = function() {         
    fs.open(filename, "r", function(error, fd) {               
        fs.read(fd, new Buffer(bite_size), 0, bite_size, readbytes, function(err, bytecount, buff) {                                  
            console.log(buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount));
            console.log('File Changed ...'+fd);
            readbytes+=bytecount;
        });             
    });
}

watchers.push({
    client_id: some_client_id,
    watcherFunction: watcherFunction
})

fs.watchFile(filename, watcherFunction)
```

And then your stop file (you will need access to watchers variables, so you need either to place both routes in same file, or place this variable in a separate package and import it in both you routes files)

```
var clientWatcherIndex = watchers.findIndex(w => w.client_id === some_client_id)
var clientWatcher = watchers[clientWatcherIndex]
fs.unwatchFile(req.body.filename, clientWatcher.watcherFunction);
watchers.splice(clientWatcherIndex , 1); // remove the watcher from list
```

If you will have just one client, then ignore the watchers variable in start file, and in stop file use:

```
fs.unwatchFile(req.body.filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Valera for prompt respose. I am very grateful. I will check and will accept the answer shortly.

Comment: It worked. I put start and stop routes in same file and referred the same filename to stop route.